# Change color of text as progressbar fills below text

Tags: android, xml, layout, android-progressbar

In an android app, i need to make a layout on the top of which contains a `ProgressBar` with text as shown in image.

[image]

As you can see in this image, the text is initially of blue color and the `ProgressBar` is of white color. As the `ProgressBar` fills in blue color, what i need to implement is to change color of text to white till the part `ProgressBar` has been filled. Can someone help with the logic for same?

Comment: did you try anything? I mean it a trivial color interpolator between white and blue

Comment: @Blackbelt I have implemented a progressbar but i cant find logic to know till what part of my text has progressbar filled up. i need logic for that

Comment: is that a TextView or are you drawing it manually?

Comment: @Blackbelt its a textview with a static text

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can use `ArgbEvaluator`, to get the new color

```
final ArgbEvaluator evaluator = new ArgbEvaluator();
int color = evaluator.evaluate(progress, YOUR_BLUE_HERE, Color.WHITE);
```

progress as to be a float between `0` and `1`

Comment: Ok thanks, i will try this solution and tell if its working.

Comment: be aware of the float progress. If your progress goes from 0 to 100, you will have to divide by 100f.